# Exclude conditional routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-route

I'm building and application in `Laravel` and `Vuejs` where I'm having Laravel routes as below:

```
Route::get('/admin/{view?}', 'HomeController@admin')->where('view', '(.*)')->name('admin');

Route::get('/{view?}', 'HomeController@home')->where('view', '(.*)')->where('view', '!=', 'admin')->name('home');
```

I'm using `Vue-router` so I'm having routing in vuejs, and I'm using history mode. The problem is when I try to call `/admin` it generally calls `HomeController@home` method. even if I go deeper like `/admin/dashboard` it is calling the same `home` method. I want if `admin` prefix is being called then it should call `HomeController@admin` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its all okay for me please check this

```
Route::get('/admin/{view?}', function (){
    dd('okay');
})->where('view', '(.*)')->name('admin');

Route::get('/{view?}', function(){
    dd('okay1');
})->where('view', '(.*)')->name('home');
```

So try this

```
Route::get('/admin/{view?}', 'HomeController@admin')->where('view', '(.*)')->name('admin');

Route::get('/{view?}', 'HomeController@home')->where('view', '(.*)')->name('home');
```